# Google maps markerclusterer custom icon based on cluster contents

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

#### Libraries

I am using google maps v3 along with [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html).

#### My use case

On a map, I am plotting differently colored circles at locations. These circles represent a specific event, based on color. Something like this:

`var circleColor = {
    completed: 'grey',
    emergency: 'red',
    nonemergency: 'blue,
    defconone: 'purple',
    defcontwo: 'navy',
    // ... and so on.
}`

These colors and events are user-defined. A user could use only one color or they could make a custom color table with hundreds of key/value pairs. Many of these circles will be to the same location on the map. We're talking anywhere from 2 in a stack to 100 on a stack. That's where marker clusterer comes in.

We cluster the icons to get a sense of how dense the circles are at any given concentration. However, what's more important is the composition of the clusters. 25 grey circles means nothing, but 24 grey circles and 1 red circle is a big deal.

I want the clusters to have a label above them that shows each cluster's composition:

`2 (red)    // Just a red dot.
 3 (grey)   // Grey dot.
17 (purple) // Purple dot.
   [22]     // Normal cluster enumeration icon.`

#### Attempts

The closest I have come is to use a MarkerClustererPlus `calculator` to get the list of summarized markers, and to check the composition of circles for that cluster.

```
var calcSummary = function (markers, numStyles) {
  var colorCount = {},
      i,
      j,
      colorKeys;
  for (i = 0, j = markers.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (!colorCount[markers[i].FlagColor]) {
      colorCount[markers[i].FlagColor] = 0;
    }
    colorCount[markers[i].FlagColor] += 1;
  }

  console.log(colorCount); // colorCount is what I need

  // Needed to not break things.
  return {
    text: markers.length,
    index: 0,
  }
};
```

Normally, you would use calculator to specify which style out of a set you want to use for that cluster. The reason that this won't work for me is because the events and colors are user-defined.

I think I somehow need to attack the `colorCount` variable to the cluster itself, then generate an independent map label (via canvas drawing) and open it next to the normal cluster icon, then attach its visibility to that icon.

Does anyone have any advice, whether it be an alternative solution, or some documentation I haven't come across?

Comment: Have you gone through this library: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Comment: @KayAnn Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I have seen that one. I assume you are pointing toward Marker Clusterer Plus.  Although it is geared towards large amounts of markers, it couldn't handle some of my larger use-cases (500 markers, for example.)

Comment: This particular library is fit to handle markers in thousands. I guess the issue with the color count algorithm which I am not quite confident about, I will dig a little and get back to you.

Comment: Please do! I wrote a custom clustering solution that only handles markers that are exactly on top of eachother, but that's far from ideal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show me your implementation for user defined markers and also the key,value pair? Also, do you store those value in a database or cache it out?